# Replacing a part of path

Tags: sed, grep

I have a folder with many subfolders containing files with lines like this: `version/1.1/...` or `version/1.1.1/...`
I want to replace all version numbers for version 1.2 like this: `version/1.2/...`
Before replacing I want to display all version numbers uses in all files in this hierarchy. How can I do it using `grep` and `sed`?

What I've tried:

```
grep -Ri "version\/([0-9].[0-9](?:.[0-9])?)\/" .
grep -Ril "version\/([0-9].[0-9](?:.[0-9])?)\/" . | xargs sed sed -i -e 's/(version\/([0-9].[0-9](?:.[0-9])?)\/)/(1.2)/g'
```

Comment: POSIX regex does not support non-capturing groups, and `?` is not a quantifier in POSIX BRE. `"version\/([0-9].[0-9](?:.[0-9])?)\/"` must be written as `"version/[0-9]\.[0-9]\(\.[0-9]\)\{0,1\}/"` and after removing a duplicated `sed` you can try `sed -i 's/\(version\/[0-9]\.[0-9]\(\.[0-9]\)\{0,1\}\/\).*/\11.2/g'`. Check [the code here](https://ideone.com/HEoccv).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  It's replace "..." in "version/1.1.1/..." but I would like to change only number of version - "1.1.1" - and not modify the part of path after this number (...)

Comment: Aha, try `xargs sed -i 's/\(version\/\)[0-9.]*/\11.2/g'`, see [this code](https://ideone.com/jePv6B).

Answer (score 0):

POSIX regex does not support non-capturing groups, and `?` is not a quantifier in POSIX BRE, it just matches a literal `?` char. If you are using GNU `sed`, you may escape `?` to make it a quantifier, or use the `-E` option to make the pattern POSIX ERE compliant.

The grep `"version\/([0-9].[0-9](?:.[0-9])?)\/"` pattern must be written as `"version/[0-9]\.[0-9]\(\.[0-9]\)\{0,1\}/"` (again, it is a POSIX BRE pattern, capturing groups are defined with `\(...\)` and range quantifiers are specified using `\{min,max\}`). Do not forget to escape the literal `.` char when it is used outside of bracket expressions.

After removing a duplicated `sed` word (you have `sed sed`) you can use

```sh
sed -i 's/\(version\/\)[0-9.]*/\11.2/g'
```

It will match and capture `version/` string into Group 1 and then will match zero or more digits or dots and will replace with the Group 1 value (`\1`) and `1.2` string.

Full command:

```sh
grep -Ril "version/[0-9]\.[0-9]\(\.[0-9]\)\{0,1\}/" . | \
 xargs sed -i 's/\(version\/\)[0-9.]*/\11.2/g'
```